# How to do something synchronous inside a asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
const readline = require('readline')
const stream = require('stream')

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('logs_out.txt')
})

var items = new Set()

// ASYNC FUNCTION READING LINE BY LINE

rl.on('line', function(line) {
   let log = JSON.parse(line)
    // ADDING ITEMS TO A SET TO GET UNIQUE ITEMS COUNT
   items.add(log.resource)
})

// PRINTING OUT THE SIZE OF THE SET
console.log(items.size)
```

Now the issue is, when I do this I always get undefined or 0 for the size of the set because the `console.log(items.size)` is executed even before all the `line` functions are executed.

How to fix this.

Thank You.

Comment: Yes it looks like a possible duplicate with the additional complexity of having multiple asynchronous calls.

Comment: A clear answer would be really appreciated, as I have just started out in JS it is a little difficult for me to understand all the concepts in that linked answer.

Comment: @deadpool put the last line into sth like `rl.on("end",function(){ /*here*/ })`

Comment: @Jonasw Thanks mate, I used the close event and it worked, but any idea how to call something synchronous from async somewhere else where events like close are not available?

Comment: @deadpool they are always avilable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted as a possible duplicate by @str, there's a superb answer already here on Stack Overflow for why you might be best off with just embracing the asynchronous approach: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

For your specific problem, I suggest you just use the [`close`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close) event from `readline`.

> The readline.Interface instance should be considered to be "finished" once the 'close' event is emitted.

In your example, you can use the following:

```
// PRINTING OUT THE SIZE OF THE SET
rl.on('close', function() {
    console.log(items.size)
}
```